# how to change input date format

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a input field which is date. It looks like this
[output image i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipIGY.png)

It was showing `dd/mm/yyyy` in UI. But my need was `yyyy/mm/dd`. It should show `yyyy/mm/dd` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`

Code I tried:

```
export default function App() {
const onDateChange = (dateValue) =>{
console.log(dateValue)
}
return (
<div>
<input onChange = {(e)=>{onDateChange(e.target.value)} } type="date" format='yyyy/mm/dd' />
</div>
);
}
```

My need was `yyyy/mm/dd`. It should show `yyyy/mm/dd` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy` 
I tried searching stackoverflow. Some answers shows, it changes depends upon the locale. But I need it to be `yyyy/mm/dd` everytime fixed. I tried a lot. But cant find solutions. Please help me with some solutions

Answer (score 0):

For a better experience with dates, I'd recommend you to use the day.js library, it's quite small but very useful, in it you can find an option to format your dates as you wish
e.g. `dayjs().format(YYYY-MM-DD)`

Hope it works for you

Comment: I need to show it in UI. It can help me to process dates. but For Frontend UI, i want to show that format

Answer (score -1):

To set and get the input type date in dd-mm-yyyy format we will use  type attribute. The  type attribute is used to define a date picker or control field. In this attribute, you can set the range from which day-month-year to which day-month-year date can be selected from.

Comment: 1. `dd-mm-yyyy` is the format OP doesn't want to use, and 2. this reads very much like a Chat GPT answer, which are currently banned on Stack Overflow (see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). If it *is* from Chat GPT, please consider deleting the answer (also: it's wrong, and fails to answer the presented problem).